# Visualization of how Google storage space is used

Tags: google-drive, google-account, account-management

Google has a limit of 15 GB storage space per account for consumer (free) accounts.  Is there a simple procedure to visualize how the 15GB is used (photos, videos, email, documents)?  Ideally, there would be a pie chart and a list of the biggest files.

The goal is to quickly understand which files are taking up the most space.

Answer (score 2):

You can visit https://drive.google.com/u/2/settings/storage and login through the Gmail account for which you need to get the details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a pie chart like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ4kX.png)**, however now it looks different:

**https://one.google.com/storage?i=m**

---

> [image]

- **[Google Drive storage guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/171788/how-to-free-up-storage-space-on-your-google-account-the-ultimate-guide/)**

Comment: This doesn't show which **files** are taking the most of the storage space.

Answer (score 1):

Google is transforming how they are informing users how their information is being handled. As today, March 1st., 2019, on https://myaccount.google.com/data-and-personalization we could find widget showing the total storage space used but to find which files are the largest we should go to each of the three apps that use that space: Gmail, Google Drive and Google Photos.

- On Gmail use the search operator `larger:` followed by a size, i.e. `larger:24mb`
- On Google Drive

  - for regular files go to https://drive.google.com/drive/quota
  - for apps backups like the Whats App backup on Google Drive go to https://drive.google.com > Settings > Manage applications
- On Google Photos, I'm not sure if this could be done on the web app.