# How to find out what is taking up Google Drive space?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I had a promotion active on my Google drive that gave me 200GB for 2 years. That promotion is up now and I seem to be using 48GB out of the 17GB allowed for free accounts.

This affects my gmail as well and if I dont fix this I will stop getting emails.

My memory management shows that Google Drive is using 40GB, Gmail is using 4GB and 4GB.

I cant see to figure out what is taking up so much space in Google drive. I tried using https://drive.google.com/drive/quota but even summing up all the large files listed there it still does not add up to 48Gb or anything even lose to it.

How do I find out what is taking up all this space?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visualization of how Google storage space is used](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124806/visualization-of-how-google-storage-space-is-used)

Comment: Can you please state why you don't want to buy a subscription?