# How do I see which files are taking up the most space on my Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-api

I would like to be able to stay under my quota. Currently, I have 100GBs of Drive space and I don't think that I need anymore.

I found that I can Empty the Trash but I would like to remove only the largest files permanently that I don't need anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visualization of how Google storage space is used](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124806/visualization-of-how-google-storage-space-is-used)

Answer (score 1):

Simply navigate to this page and Google Drive will sort your largest files by size. This will allow you to stay under your quota.

https://drive.google.com/drive/quota

source: https://gsuitetips.com/tips/drive/use-quota-to-find-out-file-sizes-in-google-drive/